# Laravel 5.2 database migration error occurs when second table migrate

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 5.2. I did create migration file with `php artisan make:migration create_users_table` command. File created successfully and I did update file with this code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('partner_id');
            $table->string('social_id');
            $table->integer('device_id');
            $table->integer('gcm_id');
            $table->integer('user_role');
            $table->string('social_media');
            $table->string('display_name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('profile_pic');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->float('height');
            $table->float('weight');
            $table->string('dob');
            $table->bigInteger('mobile');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->integer('zip');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->float('latitude');
            $table->float('longitude');
            $table->float('gps_status');
            $table->string('favorite_movie');
            $table->string('favorite_food');
            $table->string('favorite_weather');
            $table->integer('login_status');
            $table->string('active');
            $table->string('token');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}`
```

for running migration i use this 'php artisan migrate' command. and error occurs

'Migration table created successfully.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1025 Error on rename of '.\laravel\users' to
>   '.\laravel#sql2-1d88-70' (errno: 190 - Operation not allowed when
>   innodb_forced_recov   ery > 0) (SQL: alter table `users` add unique
>   `users_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on
>   rename of '.\laravel\users' to '.\laravel#sql2-1d88-70' (errno: 190 -
>   Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recov   ery > 0)'

After that I used rollback command `php artisan migrate:rollback` but message shows nothing to rollback and when I want to create second table the message shows `the user table already exist`.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan migrate:fresh`? it looks like you have the old database still there

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem with the rollback is that since the migration hasn't finished correctly, the process to add the migration in the db table (as a final step) has not been triggered and therefore the artisan command cannot revert it. To solve this I would suggest you to manually delete the table from the DB.

The problem thought is on the migration itself, on top of my head I can't remember if a fresh installation of Laravel already comes with a users table, check that first of all. If it does then u need to alter the table instead of creating it. If not, I can;t see any obvious reason for the migration to fail.